# Is there an easy way to detect at runtime, whether JRuby profiling is enabled?

Tags: profiling, jruby

When profiling only parts of my JRuby program, I proceed as follows: I pass the option `--profile.api` to JRuby, and then do something like:

```ruby
require 'jruby/profiler'
pdata = JRuby::Profiler.profile { my_code_to_be_profiled }
```

If the caller of the program forgets to pass `--profile.api`, the `profile` method raises an exception.

I now would like to test at runtime, whether profiling is enabled or not.  How can this be done in a good way? One possibility would be to just try profiling an empty block and see whether I get an exception:

```ruby
require 'jruby/profiler'
profiling_enabled = true # Let's be optimistic
begin
  JRuby::Profiler.profile {}
rescue RuntimeError
  profiling_enabled = false
end
```

This works, but doesn't look very elegant. Can anybody offer a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work:

```ruby
if JRuby.runtime.instance_config.is_profiling
  pdata = JRuby::Profiler.profile { my_code_to_be_profiled }
end
```